# RichTextBox text blinking

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, paint

does someone know, how to make various parts of `RichTextBox` text to blink in **.NET** on **Winforms**?
Or maybe this is already done?(Google gave no help)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you need a timer. after selecting a text and click the blink button save the region of the text (startposition:endposition) to an array. With the timer change every second(for example) the color of the text in regions saved in the array. if the text is changed check if the change occured in a region and inrecrease or shrink the region. if the text is change outside a region check if the blinking text is moved and move the region also backward/foreward.